# Restore fails on ovirt whether engine is on or off - how to get around

Tags: linux, oracle, ovirt

Wondering whether this is an issue;

I had an engine where i created a backup and stored elsewhere. This engine was reinstalled
and the backup file (called file_name) used to restore below. However i get 2 different
errors based on whether engine is on....

```
[root@dub-mgrfarm113 ~]# service ovirt-engine status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status ovirt-engine.service
● ovirt-engine.service - oVirt Engine
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ovirt-engine.service; disabled; vendor preset:
disabled)
Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-01-16 16:13:41 GMT; 2h 5min ago
Main PID: 5621 (ovirt-engine.py)
CGroup: /system.slice/ovirt-engine.service
├─5621 /usr/bin/python
/usr/share/ovirt-engine/services/ovirt-engine/ovirt-engine.py --redirect-output
--systemd=notify st...
└─5661 ovirt-engine -server -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms1991M -Xmx1991M -Xss1M
-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.clien...

Jan 16 16:13:40 dub-mgrfarm113.ie.oracle.com systemd[1]: Starting oVirt Engine...
Jan 16 16:13:40 dub-mgrfarm113.ie.oracle.com ovirt-engine.py[5621]: 2020-01-16
16:13:40,816+0000 ovirt-engine: INFO _detectJBossV...l=36
Jan 16 16:13:41 dub-mgrfarm113.ie.oracle.com ovirt-engine.py[5621]: 2020-01-16
16:13:41,795+0000 ovirt-engine: INFO _detectJBossV...'[]'
Jan 16 16:13:41 dub-mgrfarm113.ie.oracle.com systemd[1]: Started oVirt Engine.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
[root@dub-mgrfarm113 ~]# engine-backup --mode=restore --file=file_name
--restore-permissions
Start of engine-backup with mode 'restore'
scope: all
archive file: file_name
log file: /var/log/ovirt-engine-backup/ovirt-engine-restore-20200116181932.log
Preparing to restore:
FATAL: Engine service is active - can not restore backup
```

or off.......

```
[root@dub-mgrfarm113 ~]# service ovirt-engine stop
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl stop ovirt-engine.service
[root@dub-mgrfarm113 ~]# engine-backup --mode=restore --file=file_name
--restore-permissions
Start of engine-backup with mode 'restore'
scope: all
archive file: file_name
log file: /var/log/ovirt-engine-backup/ovirt-engine-restore-20200116181952.log
Preparing to restore:
- Unpacking file 'file_name'
Restoring:
- Files
FATAL: Can't connect to database 'engine'. Please see
'/usr/bin/engine-backup --help'.
```

In addition, possibly related, the web page for the server will no longer launch even when
ovirt-engine and httpd services are running while.

Any troubleshooting tips or has anyone seen same before?

Comment: Which version of oVirt are you using? Is it a self-hosted engine? Is the backup taken from the same major release of oVirt as you are trying to restore to?